# lwjgl attach or union shapes to make transparancy look correct

Tags: java, lwjgl

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now. Is there a way to have multiple shapes you have rendered to become one single object? So you could manipulate the object in any way you want? Currently if I try to use the glcolor method it doesn't change anything because I have multiple colors changing the objects already. Maybe I'm not realizing something obvious, or it's just something that I can't find in any tutorial. But simply put I'm looking for a way to change just the alpha value of multiple shapes draw together to make a more complex shape, but keeping the colors that have already been predefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want multiple shapes to become one single object you simply calculate or write the correct X, Y, Z numbers into each vertex, so they fit together.

For instance you can make 2 triangles become a square, like this.

[image]

To do the same but in code it would look something like this.

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 0f);
glVertex3f(0f, 100f, 0f);
glVertex3f(100f, 0f, 0f);

glVertex3f(100f, 100f, 0f);
glVertex3f(100f, 0f, 0f);
glVertex3f(0f, 100f, 0f);

glEnd();
```

You can of course just use `GL_QUADS`, though triangles are usually better in a lot of ways. If you want to color the shape 1 color, you need and can only write one color before.

So for instance this will work and gives a whole red square/quad.

```
glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);

glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

glVertex3f(0f, 0f, 0f);
glVertex3f(0f, 100f, 0f);
glVertex3f(100f, 0f, 0f);

glVertex3f(100f, 100f, 0f);
glVertex3f(100f, 0f, 0f);
glVertex3f(0f, 100f, 0f);

glEnd();
```

Though if you add more `glColor` in between that will end up giving another result.

If you want to use transparency/opacity/alpha you will need to use `glColor4f` where the last number is the amount of transparency. But before you are able to use transparency you need to enable blending mode within OpenGL. You do that by calling.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I wasn't a 100% sure about your questions so if I've forgotten to answer something, just write a comment and tell me.

#### Info

If you don't statically import your classes then remember that `glEnable(GL_BLEND);` is actually `GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);` and the same goes for the rest of the code.

Also take in mind that the `glVertex`, `glNormal`, `glColor`, etc. are deprecated methods and should not be used for that reason, also they are extremely slow when rendering a huge amount of vertices, **Though they are really good for the purpose of learning OpenGL, and should only be used for learning.** The new and better alternative is to use VBOs and Shaders.

Comment: Thanks for the thought out answer, you were correct on my question. I just wish there was quicker ways to draw complicated shapes for the lazy. :p

Comment: Well using the glVertex, glColor, glNormal, etc. methods they are actually deprecated. Now you are suppose to VBOs and Shaders, do you know what those are, else I can edit my answer to show you! :)

Comment: I actually just found what I was looking for. It's called "Render to texture." I feel dumb for not searching it this way in the first place. Thanks. EDIT: I have been looking at lwjgl for a bit. It's just acts a little different from anything else I've done. Starting to get a hang of it better. I think anyway. :p